# How to detect number of rings of an incoming call in android?

Tags: android

Using a `BroadcastReceiver` I am able to detect any incoming call by using an `intent_filter` in `androidManifest` file as follows.

```
<receiver android:name=".EventReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Now, I would like to detect/count number of times the call has rung i.e.
when a caller calls, he/she hears rings (tring-tring), I would like to count these rings in android.

Could anyone please guide me in this?

Comment: people use custom ringtones what do you actually want check the answer below

Comment: caller could hear only tring-tring and no ringtone, right? I would like to count the number of such rings. Just try it would @Elltz, you will understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: okay i understand now. i guess its simple, i ticks every 2 secs, so you can start counting after you get the broadcast that the user has initiated the call, and you count the time from there, at most the caller will be waiting for 30 seconds plus any adittional time from the provider being leaving a voicemail etc etc, so your max count will be 30/2 .. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I would keep this solution as a backup. Actually I was evaluating other alternatives. I was wondering if android has a function/API in TelephonyManager or somewhere which would help me do this.

Comment: hmm i have never really heard of that, and well i do not know because i have not seen, but hey you never know maybe someone might pop up with a better solution.you are always welcome,btw i had to do the Edit so i can undo the downvote as i did not understand your question earlier, apologies.